# Macro to define javascript constructor keyword

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, macros

I have many classes which are like this:

```
struct A_Insert
{
    Data &d;
    A_Insert(d) : d(d){}

    // ...
}

struct A_Query
{
    Data &d;
    A_Query(d) : d(d){}

    // ...
}

struct B_Insert
{
    Data &d;
    B_Insert(d) : d(d){}

    // ...
}

struct B_Query
{
    Data &d;
    B_Query(d) : d(d){}

    // ...
}
```

The best thing I can think to do is define a macro like this:

```
#define Data_Query(name, body) struct name{Data &d; name(Data &d) : d(d) {} body}
```

but this leads to somewhat ugly code as I have to use parentheses to define my structs and my IDE doesn't handle it very well.

```
Data_Query(A_Insert, 
    int bind_params(stmt &stmt){}
    ...
)
```

I would like a macro which could allow me to get the name of the containing type for the constructor so I could write code like:

```
#define constructor CONTAINING_TYPE
#define Data_Construct Data &d; constructor (Data &d) : d(d) {}
```

struct A_Insert
{
Data_Construct
// ...
}

and this way my IDE could treat it like a normal `struct` declaration. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: it is the nature of macros that they lead to somewhat ugly code. It is not clear why you want to use a macro in the first place.

Comment: @idclev463035818 it can sometimes be tedious to type out the name of the class for each new constructor. I would like if there was something like the javascript constructor keyword which define a constructor while making it easy to copy and paste and keeping the code very readable. I will add that to my question.

Comment: I don't see any reason for this. If you are using a halfway decent IDE it sure supports templates and auto complete.

Comment: @churill, how could I use templates to help me with this? EDIT: I have no idea what text templates are but I will look it up.

Comment: @idclev463035818 it is the nature of templates that they lead to somewhat ugly code. it is the nature of classes that they lead to somewhat ugly code. it is the nature of loops that they lead to somewhat ugly code. it is the nature of programming languages that they lead to somewhat ugly code. it is the nature of everything that they lead to somewhat ugly code.

Comment: @trinalbadger587 To clarify: not C++ templates, but text-templates, like VS code has. Where you can insert a bunch of code at once and fill the gaps with a class name for example. (in fact they are called snippets, sorry)

Comment: @bipll true words, but I dare to claim that code with macros tends to be more ugly than code without

Comment: @idclev463035818 I personally would find a 'constructor' keyword the most elegant way to do this. I would actually use that all the time since I don't really like having to change my constructors when I change the name of my types. I am not sure if it possible but if it is, I would like to have it. I don't think it would make the code any more ugly though my Data_Query and Data_Construct macros sure would.

Comment: No, it is not possible in C++. Of course almost everything is possible with macros, but where I work, it is only possible *once*.

Comment: frankly your example fails to demonstrate a reasonable use-case. Your classes are all the same and there is no obvious need to write a contructor for one type more than once. On the other hand if the types are different, then the constructors are also different and the name of the types being different is the smaller "problem"

Comment: @idclev463035818 so do they constitute a better criterion to distinguish fine art from mere craft? :)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Basically, the way my code works is I have a class for a query and then functions which calls the various function on the class to execute the query. My classes aren't all the same they call different queries. They query based on the different variables in my data. So, for example I could have one for querying based on who created a level. So, I would have Person_Query and it would write the data to the reference and I would use the same data structure to insert things and query things based on different variables. I am not sure if there is a better way of doing it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance:

```
struct DataReference
{
    Data &d;
    
    DataReference(Data& d) : d(d) {}
};

struct A_Insert : DataReference
{
    using DataReference::DataReference;

    ...
};
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `using DataReference::DataReference;`? This seems to pull the `DataReference` constructor into lookups within `A_Insert`, but it's already found there anyway. I don't see any purpose to it, am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know. But the compiler I use right now has a c++ version that doesn't automatically do that.

Comment: @ArthurTacca I tried it without that and it didn't work. I don't really understand it but it seems to work.

Comment: Ah I see: I thought that in the `...` you were intending to declare another constructor that made use of `DataReference`'s constructor. But actually you're suggesting that you don't write a constructor at all on the derived class at all. Instead, the `using` turns the `DataReference(Data& d) ` into a `A_Insert(Data& d)` constructor automatically.

Comment: This is the closest thing to what I wanted of having a constructor without having to write the declaring type because the 'using' doesn't require the name of the containing type.